# Using a USB controller as auxiliary keyboard for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, usb

Our family no longer uses our [Mixman DM2](http://www.mixman.com/products/dm2.html) USB controller for making music.  This frees it up for me to use as an auxiliary keyboard with 31 "keys" (and a few "sliders").  I had the crazy idea to use these buttons to send keyboard shortcuts to Visual Studio.  It just seems easier pressing one key than some of the finger-bending ctrl double-key combos.

I tried a couple utilities like JoyToKey and XPadder but they only recognize game controllers and the DM2 falls into the more generic "USB Controller" category.

Have you ever heard of such nonsense?

**Clarify Question:** Are you aware of a utility to read inputs from a generic USB Controller and map them to keyboard key presses? -OR- Are you aware of a Visual Studio add-in that will read from a generic USB Controller?

Comment: No progress so far.  I played with some different ideas but I still have not found a proper solution...

Comment: Ok, so this is a 3+ year old question, so I'm a little late to the game. I've got a Hercules MK2 DJ controller that I'm trying to do the same thing with. You can map midi signals to keystrokes with "Bome's Midi Translator". However, even though I see the midi signals are getting translated to signals (for example, if I have notepad open, I can see the characters getting typed), Visual Studio is ignoring them. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't heard of it before, but I can't wait to see if you can make it useful!

You can assign Visual Studio functions to "chords" of key combinations, right?  So maybe you could play shave-and-a-haircut to start a build.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I was thinking about doing something similiar to that myself. I'm pretty sure you'd have to write your own driver for it though.